# Content are disappeared if elements are added in add_mutually_exclusive_group

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I add these arguments (data and size) in add_argument_group(), I  got the expected output:

```
     Mydata = cli_parser.add_argument_group()
     Mydata .add_argument("--data", "-a", dest="data", action="store", help="User-specified payload." )
     Mydata .add_argument("--size", "-s", dest="size", action="store", help="User-specified size." )
```

OUPUT:

```
     ./test [-h] [--data DATA ] [--size SIZE]
     --data DATA, -a DATA                    User-specified payload.
     --size SIZE, -s SIZE                    User-specified size.
```

When I add both are arguments( data and size)  in mutually exclusive groups, the "help" part is disappeared from the output.

```
    Mydata = cli_parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    Mydata .add_argument("--data", "-a", dest="data", action="store", help="User-specified payload." )
    Mydata .add_argument("--size", "-s", dest="size", action="store", help="User-specified size." )
```

I can see only the following output.

```
    ./test [-h] (--data DATA | --size SIZE)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code and the output seems correct. I'm using Win10, Python 3.8.

```
import argparse

cli_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

Mydata = cli_parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
Mydata .add_argument("--data", "-a", dest="data", action="store", help="User-specified payload." )
Mydata .add_argument("--size", "-s", dest="size", action="store", help="User-specified size." )
cli_parser.print_help()
```

Output

```
usage: paramtest.py [-h] (--data DATA | --size SIZE)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --data DATA, -a DATA  User-specified payload.
  --size SIZE, -s SIZE  User-specified size.
```

Are you doing something different in your code?